# Custom validator not working with drop down menu in sjf

Tags: jsf-2

I have a custom validator for drop down menu in jsf. But this custom validator never gets invoked.

Below is the code having custom validator categoryValidator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">


      <h:head>
          <h:title>Add Category</h:title>
      </h:head>

      <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel id="catNameLabel" value="Category name" for="j_catName"/>
                <h:inputText id="j_catName" value="#{categoryActionBean.category.name}" required="true"
                  label="Cateory name">
                   <f:validateRequired />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="j_catName" style="color:red;"/>

                <h:outputLabel id="catDescLabel" value="category Description" for="j_catDesc"/>
                <h:inputText id="j_catDesc" value="#{categoryActionBean.category.description}" required="true"
                  label="Category Description">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message for="j_catDesc" style="color:red;"/>

                <h:outputLabel id="selParentCatLabel" value="Parent Category" for="j_selParentCat"/>
                <h:selectOneMenu id="j_selParentCat" value="#{categoryActionBean.selectedParentCategory}"
                 label="Selected category">
                     <f:validator validatorId="categoryValidator"/>
                     <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="">
                         <f:param name="isParent" value=""/>
                     </f:selectItem>
                     <c:forEach items="#{categoryActionBean.categories}" var="catMap">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{catMap.key}" itemLabel="#{catMap.value.name}">
                           <f:param name="isParent" value="false"/>
                        </f:selectItem>
                     </c:forEach>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:message for="j_selParentCat" style="color:red;"/>

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="Save category" action="#{categoryActionBean.saveCategory}" type="submit"/>
          </h:form>  
      </h:body>

</html>
```

Below is my custom validator .

```
package com.auction.jsf.validator;



import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator("categoryValidator")
public class CategoryValidator implements Validator{

      @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {


             System.out.println("Inside category validator");

         // My validation logic
         ---
         ---
         ---

         if(validationFalied) {
                   throw new ValidatorException(facesMessage);

         }
        }

}
```

The categoryValidator for select menu is not invoked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you register your validator in `faces-config.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your custom validator in `faces-config.xml`

```
<validator>
    <validator-id>customValidator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>path to this categoryValidator class</validator-class>
</validator>
```

or you can annotate directly in Jsf 2.0 +versions

```
 @FacesValidator("path to this categoryValidator class")
    public class CategoryValidator {

}
```

But don't do both.Even you do it `faces-config.xml` takes precedence.

Comment: Yes i have annotated my validator with annotation FacesValidator. The validator gets invoked if it is used for input text, but does not get invoked for select menu.

Comment: Can you add validator class to question?

Comment: I have added my validator class to the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a  Bean Validation (JSR 303) for selectedParentCategory,
see Using BeanValidation on Jeetutorial6 Pag 206.